# How to specify jhipster filter criteria where request param in url is string but needs to map to enum in backend

Tags: rest, filter, spring-data-jpa, jhipster, enumeration

I am working on a project that is generated using jhipster. For a given field in an entity, the values are an enum. With filtering enabled on entity, how to query the entity on enum value

api/users?role.equals=admin

Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'application.domain.enumeration.Roles' for property 'role.equals'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [application.domain.enumeration.Roles] for value 'admin'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant application.domain.enumeration.Roles.admin

I believe i need to write a custom specification but not sure how to proceed

list of objects whose user type is admin

Controller Code:

```
package org.XXX.web.rest;

import com.codahale.metrics.annotation.Timed;

import io.github.jhipster.web.util.ResponseUtil;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import javax.validation.Valid;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

/**
 * REST controller for managing Users.
 */
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class UsersResource {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UsersResource.class);

    private static final String ENTITY_NAME = "serviceUsers";

    private final UsersService usersService;

    private final UsersQueryService usersQueryService;

    public UsersResource(UsersService usersService, UsersQueryService usersQueryService) {
        this.usersService = usersService;
        this.usersQueryService = usersQueryService;
    }

    /**
     * POST  /users : Create a new users.
     *
     * @param usersDTO the usersDTO to create
     * @return the ResponseEntity with status 201 (Created) and with body the new usersDTO, or with status 400 (Bad Request) if the users has already an ID
     * @throws URISyntaxException if the Location URI syntax is incorrect
     */
    @PostMapping("/users")
    @Timed
    public ResponseEntity<UsersDTO> createUsers(@Valid @RequestBody UsersDTO usersDTO) throws URISyntaxException {
        log.debug("REST request to save Users : {}", usersDTO);
        if (usersDTO.getId() != null) {
            throw new BadRequestAlertException("A new users cannot already have an ID", ENTITY_NAME, "idexists");
        }
        UsersDTO result = usersService.save(usersDTO);
        return ResponseEntity.created(new URI("/api/users/" + result.getId()))
            .headers(HeaderUtil.createEntityCreationAlert(ENTITY_NAME, result.getId().toString()))
            .body(result);
    }

    /**
     * PUT  /users : Updates an existing users.
     *
     * @param usersDTO the usersDTO to update
     * @return the ResponseEntity with status 200 (OK) and with body the updated usersDTO,
     * or with status 400 (Bad Request) if the usersDTO is not valid,
     * or with status 500 (Internal Server Error) if the usersDTO couldn't be updated
     * @throws URISyntaxException if the Location URI syntax is incorrect
     */
    @PutMapping("/users")
    @Timed
    public ResponseEntity<UsersDTO> updateUsers(@Valid @RequestBody UsersDTO usersDTO) throws URISyntaxException {
        log.debug("REST request to update Users : {}", usersDTO);
        if (usersDTO.getId() == null) {
            throw new BadRequestAlertException("Invalid id", ENTITY_NAME, "idnull");
        }
        UsersDTO result = usersService.save(usersDTO);
        return ResponseEntity.ok()
            .headers(HeaderUtil.createEntityUpdateAlert(ENTITY_NAME, usersDTO.getId().toString()))
            .body(result);
    }

    /**
     * GET  /users : get all the users.
     *
     * @param pageable the pagination information
     * @param criteria the criterias which the requested entities should match
     * @return the ResponseEntity with status 200 (OK) and the list of users in body
     */
    @GetMapping("/users")
    @Timed
    public ResponseEntity<List<UsersDTO>> getAllUsers(UsersCriteria criteria, Pageable pageable) {
        log.debug("REST request to get Users by criteria: {}", criteria);
        Page<UsersDTO> page = usersQueryService.findByCriteria(criteria, pageable);
        HttpHeaders headers = PaginationUtil.generatePaginationHttpHeaders(page, "/api/users");
        return new ResponseEntity<>(page.getContent(), headers, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    /**
     * GET  /users/:id : get the "id" users.
     *
     * @param id the id of the usersDTO to retrieve
     * @return the ResponseEntity with status 200 (OK) and with body the usersDTO, or with status 404 (Not Found)
     */
    @GetMapping("/users/{id}")
    @Timed
    public ResponseEntity<UsersDTO> getUsers(@PathVariable Long id) {
        log.debug("REST request to get Users : {}", id);
        Optional<UsersDTO> usersDTO = usersService.findOne(id);

        return ResponseUtil.wrapOrNotFound(usersDTO);
    }

    /**
     * DELETE  /users/:id : delete the "id" users.
     *
     * @param id the id of the usersDTO to delete
     * @return the ResponseEntity with status 200 (OK)
     */
    @DeleteMapping("/users/{id}")
    @Timed
    public ResponseEntity<Void> deleteUsers(@PathVariable Long id) {
        log.debug("REST request to delete Users : {}", id);
        usersService.delete(id);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(HeaderUtil.createEntityDeletionAlert(ENTITY_NAME, id.toString())).build();
    }
}
```

Enum Code:

```
package org.XXX.domain.enumeration;

/**
 * The Roles enumeration.
 */
public enum Roles {
    NODE, REGIONALADMIN, ADMIN;


    public static Roles getRoleSearch(String input) {
        switch (input) {
        case "NODE":
            return NODE;
        case "REGIONALADMIN":
            return REGIONALADMIN;
        case "ADMIN":
            return ADMIN;
        default:
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: provide the code of controller method and Roles enum

Comment: it could also help telling what are you trying to accomplish as there could be another approach to solve your issue

Comment: Rest Api URL based filter on an entity field which is an enum; lets say a table user has columns name, email, phone, role; and role has values from an enum{student, teacher, parent}, i need /api/users?role=parent to work

Comment: I would recommend to extend the filter class to add the field you need, this would allow you to filter your entities the way you want/need :)

Comment: thx..shall try and update here